# Plotly Buttons with Dependent Interactions (Python)

Tags: python, plotly

I am attempting to construct a Plotly 3D scatterplot with a large number of traces and several sets of buttons that determine which subset of the traces is visible. I would like for the buttons to interact in a manner that depends on the state of the other buttons. For example, suppose Button 1 and Button 2 belong to one bar of buttons and Button A and Button B belong to another bar, and that only one button in each bar can be pressed at a time. I'd like pressing Button A while Button 1 is active to display a different subset of traces than pressing Button A while Button 2 is active.

I've included a toy example below. It has a data set of three traces and two bars of buttons, but each button's behavior is currently independent of the other buttons. I'd like the buttons to behave in a dependent manner, for example,

- 1 and A pressed: show trace 1
- 1 and B pressed: show traces 1 and 2
- 2 and A pressed: show trace 3
- 2 and B pressed: show all traces

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 20).transpose()
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(124, 252, 0)',
        size=12,
        opacity=0.8
    )
)

x2, y2, z2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 20).transpose()
trace2 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x2,
    y=y2,
    z=z2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(30, 144, 255)',
        size=12,
        opacity=0.8
    )
)

x3, y3, z3 = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 20).transpose()
trace3 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x3,
    y=y3,
    z=z3,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(220, 20, 60)',
        size=12,
        opacity=0.8
    )
)

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]

layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    )
)

button_layer_1_height = 1.12
button_layer_2_height = 1.065

updatemenus=list([
    dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(
                args=[{'visible': [True, False, True]}],
                label='Button 1',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=[{'visible': [True, True, False]}],
                label='Button 2',
                method='restyle'
            ),
        ]),
        direction = 'left',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        type = 'buttons',
        x = 0.1,
        xanchor = 'left',
        y = button_layer_1_height,
        yanchor = 'top'
    ),
    dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(
                args=[{'visible': [False, True, False]}],
                label='Button A',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=['visible', [True, False, False]],
                label='Button B',
                method='restyle'
            )
        ]),
        direction = 'left',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        type = 'buttons',
        x = 0.1,
        xanchor = 'left',
        y = button_layer_2_height,
        yanchor = 'top'
    ),
])

layout['updatemenus']=updatemenus
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename='localtest.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to this question in the following tutorial: https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2. I built a Dash app using radio items instead of buttons, and the result works great.